# How to make a height adjustable shelf / desk

Tags: railing

My application needs to have a rail like sliding system but also needs few other properties

- Vertical Slider
- Range Lock
- Range Lock should be adjustable

I've sketched the requirements for better understanding.

### Locked state 1

#### Slider should not go below minimum lock position

[image: Minimum Height Locked State Picture]

### Locked state 2

#### Slider should not go above maximum lock position

[image: Maximum height locked state picture]

### Maximum and minimum lock positions should be adjustable

#### Range 1

[image: Range 1]

#### Range 2

[image: Range 2]

### Specifics about use case

- The force will be from the top and not more than 25 kgs
- The slide up and down motion will be used 20 times a day
- The slide range adjustment will be used 5 times a day
- Maximum height lock need not support weight from above, although additional support is a plus
- Minimum height in normal state is 28 inches
- Maximum height in lifted state should be upto 46 inches i.e 18 inches taller

I'm not familiar with different types of slides or hardware for the job.

What are the types of hardware required to accomplish the task efficiently.

Comment: Is this in some why related to home improvement? - I'm not seeing any sign that it is for the question as it stands - a "slider?"

Comment: @Ecnerwal I'm trying to make a shelf with adjustable height

Comment: @SathishManohar That's the question you should be asking.  Present us with the problem you're trying to solve, (adustable height shelf).  You're narrowing the scope of potential good answers by limiting the solutions.  Who knows? Someone may have already solved this problem in a completely different way.

Comment: Are you trying to make an adjustable shelf? Or a desk that you can adjust so you can sit or stand?

Comment: @ChrisCudmore Will broaden the scope of the question. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @longneck I'm trying to make a small shelf with adjustable height, which can also have things placed on top of it, Not planning to sit or stand on it.

Comment: Can you also explain the difference between the two heights? Is this to raise lower a couple of inches or a couple of feet?

Comment: @treeNinja Added height values as well. Thanks